# Error running React app

Tags: react-native

[image]

I can't run my React app. What should I do?

Comment: share error screen dump

Answer (score 2):

In react native getstarted https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
maybe you should download Android sdk like this image:

[image: download android sdk]

And if you have install Android sdk you can try setup home environment, the way is Open the System pane under System and Security in the Control Panel, then click on Change settings.... Open the Advanced tab and click on Environment Variables.... Click on New... To create a new ANDROID_HOME user variable that points to the path to your Android SDK:

[image]

The SDK is installed, by default, at the following location:

> c:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk